# Which sensor is used in Unity Gyroscope.userAcceleration API

Tags: unity-game-engine

Does anyone know if Unity's API Gyroscope.userAcceleration (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gyroscope-userAcceleration.html) is using gyroscope sensor to work or accelerometer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit my answer:
Gyroscope.userAcceleration uses the acceleration data from the gyroscope and the accelerometer sensor of your device. (refers to linear acceleration, not rotational)

So it seems the Gyroscope class performs some sort of sensor fusion.

AccelerometerInput uses the build in accelerometer sensor of your device.

Comment: So Gyroscope.userAcceleration uses only gyroscope sensor and not even a bit of accelerometer sensor?

Answer (score 2):

I believe it must use the accelerometer, since gyroscope cannot measure accelleration (while accelerometer can be used to extract rotation to a certain degree), userAcceleration just takes out the constant part (gravity aka earth acceleration) out, so when the device is not being moved user acceleration is zero even if actual data from the accelerometer contains gravity

Comment: Exactly my thought. I'm writing a documentation on Unity's gyroscope vs accelerometer and I still don't know which sensor is used in Gyroscope.userAcceleration